Princeton's writing sample limit for PhD applications is "approximately 25 pages" -- Am I okay if I go over or under that?
Probably a dumb question, but I didn't want to piss of admissions committee with a writing sample that does not fit their expected requirement. Since the program I'm applying to asks for the writing sample to be related to the specific field of interest I've mentioned in my application, I only have my master's thesis, to an excerpt from. However, the combination of chapters I can choose, it either undershoots to 19 pages or overshoots to 33 pages. I'm confused as to which option I should go for.
Thoughts?

Does it have to be verbatim something you've already written or can you abridge/condense you thesis?

@Eds They don't mention anything specific. Although I've been told by peers to stay clear from condensing thesis for submission since the original is what has been graded and looked over by the supervisor, which would make it more credible.

Including or excluding references?

@AzorAhai-him- Including references. There are about 3 pages of references/bibliography.

If you think the 33-page one is better (at 30 pages of text), I would use it.

Many years ago, I had a colleague who submitted a paper to a journal, only to have it sent back unreviewed for exceeding a page limit.  He sent it back, decreasing the margin sizes and the space between lines a bit, but otherwise unchanged, and it was accepted without revision.   I think 33 pages is a good deal more than "approximately 25".  If the overage is largely references, I think that's OK.  I caution you to make sure your sample, whatever it is, is properly referenced.

My best guess is that either will do. Since it isn't a "hard" limit, I expect anyone who gets a longer sample will find what they need to know about you and your work within the first 25 pages and ignore the rest. But the long version does seem a bit beyond "approximately 25 pages".
The purpose of a writing sample can vary from just knowing your proficiency with English to knowing something about how you attack and resolve research questions. Lots of combined and in-between possibilities.
If you send the long version, and they object, offer to send the short one. Or, if the quality of work in the short one is up to your standards, avoid the question and send it. I'd guess that "too short" is probably worse than "too long", though 19 pages may be enough for their purposes.
Consider both the writing itself, and the content. If you send excerpts, make that clear.
